# Object reference not set to an instance of an object database username validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I can not understand the logic behind the connectionString command. I am attempting to make a username registration page that checks the availability of a user name before submitting. I have followed my ASP.NET unleashed textbook to a tee, but still I get the "object reference not set" error. Do I have to name my database and table accordingly here or am I missing something else? I have been searching the internet like crazy trying to make sense of this, but I am just confusing myself. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Here are my ShowAjaxValidator.aspx and AjaxValidator.cs pages:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="custom" Namespace="myControls" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Configuration" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

    /// <summary>
    /// Validation function that is called on both the client and server
    /// </summary>
    protected void AjaxValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (UserNameExists(args.Value))
            args.IsValid = false;
        else
            args.IsValid = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true when user name already exists
    /// in Users database table
    /// </summary>
    private bool UserNameExists(string userName)
    {
        string conString =
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersDB"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE UserName=@UserName", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
        bool result = false;
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (count > 0)
                result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Insert new user name to Users database table
    /// </summary>
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conString =
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersDB"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT Users (UserName,FavoriteColor) VALUES (@UserName,@FavoriteColor)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FavoriteColor", txtFavoriteColor.Text);
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        txtUserName.Text = String.Empty;
        txtFavoriteColor.Text = String.Empty;
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Show AjaxValidator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <asp:Label
        id="lblUserName"
        Text="User Name:"
        AssociatedControlID="txtUserName"
        Runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox
        id="txtUserName"
        Runat="server" />
    <custom:AjaxValidator
        id="AjaxValidator1"
        ControlToValidate="txtUserName"
        Text="User name already taken!"
        OnServerValidate="AjaxValidator1_ServerValidate"
        Runat="server" />

    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label
        id="lblFavoriteColor"
        Text="Favorite Color:"
        AssociatedControlID="txtFavoriteColor"
        Runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox
        id="txtFavoriteColor"
        Runat="server" />

    <br /><br />
    <asp:Button
        id="btnSubmit"
        Text="Submit"
        Runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

AjaxValidator.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace myControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Enables you to perform custom validation on both the client and server
    /// </summary>
    public class AjaxValidator : BaseValidator, ICallbackEventHandler
    {
        public event ServerValidateEventHandler ServerValidate;

        string _controlToValidateValue;

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            String eventRef = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference
              (
                this,
                "",
                "",
                ""
              );

            // Register include file
            String includeScript =
                  Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/ClientScripts/AjaxValidator.js");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("AjaxValidator",
                  includeScript);

            // Register startup script
            String startupScript =
String.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').evaluationfunction = 'AjaxValidatorEvaluateIsValid';", this.ClientID);
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AjaxValidator", startupScript, true);

            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Only do the AJAX on browsers that support it
        /// </summary>
        protected override bool DetermineRenderUplevel()
        {
            return Context.Request.Browser.SupportsCallback;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Server method called by client AJAX call
        /// </summary>
        public string GetCallbackResult()
        {
            return ExecuteValidationFunction(_controlToValidateValue).ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return callback result to client
        /// </summary>
        public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
        {
            _controlToValidateValue = eventArgument;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Server-side method for validation
        /// </summary>
        protected override bool EvaluateIsValid()
        {
            string controlToValidateValue =
this.GetControlValidationValue(this.ControlToValidate);
            return ExecuteValidationFunction(controlToValidateValue);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs the validation for both server and client
        /// </summary>
        private bool ExecuteValidationFunction(String controlToValidateValue)
        {
            ServerValidateEventArgs args = new ServerValidateEventArgs (controlToValidateValue, this.IsValid);
            if (ServerValidate != null)
                ServerValidate(this, args);
            return args.IsValid;
        }

    }

}
```

The error I am running into points to the part of the .aspx file that says:

```
string conString =
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersDB"].ConnectionString;
```

The error says that a null exception was unhanded by the user and "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I tried to add the connectionStrings to the web.config file, but I am not sure if it is using the correct syntax. Could you please tell me if this is what you were saying:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="UsersDB"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;
                    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|UsersDB.mdf;
                    Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I am now getting an SqlException that says:
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Validation_Attempt\App_Data\UsersDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I am very new to ASP and C#. Edit for bronze.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: I understand that other cases are similar to mine, but I am very new to asp and C#, and I could not comprehend the other threads being that they were not my exact situation. Eric Noren's answer was exactly what I needed to put me in the right direction, so this thread was worth it's weight in gold for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem you're trying to read a configuration value that doesn't exist and then accessing a property on that null object.

You would need a `connectionStrings` node in your web.config file which had a key of `UsersDB` which had the connection string for your database. Without it, that object is null and calling `ConnectionString` property throws the null reference exception. Once you resolve the setting, this property will work correctly.

Comment: I have added a web.config file with <connectionStrings> included in my question. I am getting a new error now. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong with this command please?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out thanks to your help! Thank you very much. All I had to do after adding the connectionStrings node was create the correct database and table names. It is currently working just as it should.